# git clone error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/pirobot/rbx1.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 35173: Connection refused

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275970/git-clone-error/) by [1059682127@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/32637/1059682127@qq.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-11-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-11-15**:
That looks like a local IP address and port number; not the public address for github. Do you have a proxy or something else installed that might be interfering with your network connectivity?

**Comment by [1059682127@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/32637/1059682127@qq.com/) on 2017-11-15**:
How can I check if I have a proxy?Thank you|

**Comment by [1059682127@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/32637/1059682127@qq.com/) on 2017-11-15**:
The error appears when I git clone,show as follows:
$ git clone https://github.com/pirobot/rbx1.git
Cloning into 'rbx1'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/pirobot/rbx1.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 35173: Connection refused

**Comment by [1059682127@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/32637/1059682127@qq.com/) on 2017-11-15**:
I can successfully view https://github.com/pirobot/rbx1.git in the browser,and I can successfully ping 127.0.0.1

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-11-15**:
127.0.0.1 is address of your own computer.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-11-15**:
Make sure you can `ping github.com`. If you can't, there are lots of networking help sites. This might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109404/why-cant-i-ping-google

**Comment by [1059682127@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/32637/1059682127@qq.com/) on 2017-11-15**:
I can ping github.com. The result is shown below:
PING github.com (192.30.255.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lb-192-30-255-112-sea.github.com (192.30.255.112): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=348 ms
64 bytes from lb-192-30-255-112-sea.github.com (192.30.255.112): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=316 ms
64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a very dirty fix for you, it should work.

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

And then

```
git clone http://192.30.253.113/pirobot/rbx1.git
```

It works for me (though I don't have the local IP problem), hope it works for you too. If it does not work, you might want to set the sslVerify back to true

---

Originally posted by [Chrizzl](https://answers.ros.org/users/31761/chrizzl/) with karma: 48 on 2017-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [1059682127@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/32637/1059682127@qq.com/) on 2017-11-15**:
Thank you for your answer! I follow your method，but get the following error!

gzh@gzh-virtual-machine:/etc$ git config --global http.sslVerify false
gzh@gzh-virtual-machine:/etc$ git clone http://192.30.253.113/pirobot/rbx1.git
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'rbx1'.: Permission denied

**Comment by [Chrizzl](https://answers.ros.org/users/31761/chrizzl/) on 2017-11-15**:
@1059682127@qq.com Sounds good. Now you just have to get user permissions to write in the folder where you are trying to clone. Right now you are cloning into /etc which is not a good idea. Try the command:
cd ~
Before calling the git clone

**Comment by [1059682127@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/32637/1059682127@qq.com/) on 2017-11-15**:
It may not be the main problem! I change it still get the mistake!

gzh@gzh-virtual-machine:~$ git clone http://192.30.255.112/pirobot/rbx1.git
Cloning into 'rbx1'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://192.30.255.112/pirobot/rbx1.git/': Couldn't connect to server

**Comment by [Chrizzl](https://answers.ros.org/users/31761/chrizzl/) on 2017-11-16**:
Yes, it is probably not the main problem, my solution tries to fix symptoms instead of the source. As mentioned by others, review your networking connection. I see you are on a Virtual Machine, so there are a lot of things that might go wrong.

**Comment by [1059682127@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/32637/1059682127@qq.com/) on 2017-11-16**:
Thanks! I have tried many ways but can't solve the problem!
I can ping github.com but I can't ping https://github.com

**Comment by [1059682127@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/32637/1059682127@qq.com/) on 2017-11-16**:
I have solve the question by unset http.proxy and https.proxy!
And check it as below:

```
env|grep -i proxy
```